# Fix thise Code (Debian Screen output)

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

This shell script dosent give me any output:

```
GID="gmod01"
PID= screen -list | grep $GID | cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/\W//g'
echo $PID
```

Echo PID is empty, how can i fix this?
I get 12055 out but it dosent copy in the value

Thank you

Comment: Fix it yourself.

Comment: The *very least* you could do is to state what you want the command to actually do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use brackets.

```
GID="gmod01"
PID=$(screen -list | grep $GID | cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/\W//g')
echo $PID
```

Comment: Dosent works... /restart: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./restart: line 2: `PID=(screen -list | grep $GID | cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/\W//g')'

Comment: Will now, needs the bracket prefixed with a $